# Mac OS X Dock - number of open windows?

Tags: macos, dock

There is one big issue for me with Dock in OS X - it does not shows you if more than one window is open in an application.

For example, I'm browsing with Firefox and a site opens a background window with some sounds - and I have no idea where it comes from. The dock does not tell you if some application opens more than one window...

Is there a way (or some application) that can add some mark to application icon in Dock if it has more than one window open?

Comment: What version of OSX - Snow Leopard( 10.6) does list the open windows if you right click on an app in the doc

Comment: Mark, Yes - 10.6 - But I want some notice on icons without clicking on them

Comment: Does this article help : "A compilation of hidden dock menu additions" at http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030617042055170

Comment: http://manytricks.com/witch/ let's you see all open windows. What command tab is to applications it is to windows (apps without open windows can be included or not based on your settings.) Not really what you are looking for, but it may solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that there doesn't appear to be anything built into the system which accomplishes this goal.

This is not to say the goal is impossible; there are addons like [Docktopus](http://www.startly.com/products/docktopus/1/) which are able to dynamically "badge" Dock icons. Thus, there is obviously some form of programming interface to the Dock which may make it possible to develop a solution, if you're inclined to software development.

After scouring Google, the only app I found which dynamically badged Dock icons on Mac OS X was Docktopus, and this is sadly not one of its options. So I think your short answer will remain, "no," for some time, again, unless you build your own. Sorry. :(